# My toilet can't flush. What should I do?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

Instead of actually flushing (or pushing) the water down the drain, it just fills with water and drains out over the course of a few minutes. Anything liquid will drain out but nothing else (not even toilet paper). It seems like it doesn't even try to flush anything away. Also, when my neighbour upstairs flushes it comes to my toilet. What can possibly be the problem, and what can I do?

Comment: Sounds like there's a blockage in the pipe downstream of your and your neighbor's toilets.

Comment: definately a blockage. Try a plunger first, both bathrooms.

Answer (score 2):

That's most likely a clog beyond the point where the drains of your toilet and your neighbour's toilet join.

You are going to need to snake that out.

Answer (score -1):

It's obvious there's a blockage - if there wasn't, everything would flow as normal.

Your neighbour's loo is backing up into yours, pointing out that the blockage is after your loo, rather than anywhere else in the line.

Getting your neighbour to not use the loo for a while while you sort out will help, if difficult.

Solutions are various, from putting chemicals down *your* loo, and flushing, which may dissolve the blockage, to using a plunger to suck up then split up the blockage, to poking a snake ( a flexible rod) as far as possible into the pipework, to employing a professional with much more sophisticated (and expensive) gear to solve the problem. Cost to be shared with neighbour.

If you're lucky, the build up won't just move further down the pipework and cause later problems. Unlucky, and some of the pipework will have to be opened up to reveal the blockage.

Obviously, start with the least expensive, and work your way through. Hope that gets you out of the mire...